# how to upload any file from local machine to database server file system using SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is my Code:

I need to upload a file from the local machine to the file system 
Also, i got an error when opening the file attached in the oracle application `(ORA-01403: no data found`

---

> FRM-40735: WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED trigger raised unhandled exception
>   ORA-01403.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY in_file_loc AS '/oracle/TEST';



CREATE TABLE test_files  (p_id NUMBER,
                          pl_name VARCHAR2(100),
                          pl_pict BLOB);



DECLARE
    x_blob                BLOB;
    fils                  BFILE   := BFILENAME ('IN_FILE_LOC', 'aa.pdf');
    blob_length           INTEGER;
BEGIN
-- Obtain the size of the blob file
   DBMS_LOB.fileopen (fils, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly);
   blob_length := DBMS_LOB.getlength (fils);
   DBMS_LOB.fileclose (fils);

-- Insert a new record into the table containing the
-- filename you have specified and a LOB LOCATOR.
-- Return the LOB LOCATOR and assign it to x_blob.
    INSERT INTO test_files (p_id,pl_name,pl_pict)
    VALUES (7, 'aa.pdf', EMPTY_BLOB ())
 RETURNING pl_pict
      INTO x_blob;

-- Load the file into the database as a BLOB
   DBMS_LOB.OPEN (fils, DBMS_LOB.lob_readonly);
   DBMS_LOB.OPEN (x_blob, DBMS_LOB.lob_readwrite);
   DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile (x_blob, fils, blob_length);
-- Close handles to blob and file
   DBMS_LOB.CLOSE (x_blob);
   DBMS_LOB.CLOSE (fils);
COMMIT;
-- Confirm insert by querying the database
-- for LOB length information and output results
   blob_length := 0;

SELECT DBMS_LOB.getlength (pl_pict)
 INTO blob_length
 FROM test_files
WHERE pl_name = 'aa.pdf';

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Successfully inserted BLOB ''' ||'aa.pdf' || ''' of size ' || blob_length || ' bytes.');
END; 


DECLARE
TYPE result_set_type IS REF CURSOR;

l_name              VARCHAR2 (100);
l_doc_size          NUMBER;
l_result_set_curr   result_set_type;
x_access_id         NUMBER;
x_file_id           NUMBER;
p_file_name         VARCHAR2 (100)  := 'aa.pdf';

PROCEDURE load_file_details (p_name IN VARCHAR2, result_set_curr OUT result_set_type)
AS
  l_error   VARCHAR2 (2000);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fnd_lobs_document
              (NAME, mime_type, doc_size, content_type, blob_content)
     SELECT pl_name, 'application/pdf', DBMS_LOB.getlength (pl_pict), 'BINARY', '(BLOB)'
       FROM test_files
      WHERE pl_name = 'aa.pdf';

  OPEN result_set_curr FOR
     SELECT blob_content
       FROM fnd_lobs_document
      WHERE NAME = p_name;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     NULL;
     l_error := 'LOAD_FILE_DETAILS - OTHERS' || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 2000);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_error);

END load_file_details;

PROCEDURE upload_file (v_filename IN VARCHAR2, x_access_id OUT NUMBER, x_file_id OUT NUMBER)
AS
  v_access_id   NUMBER;
  v_file_id     NUMBER;
  x_errbuf      VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
  v_access_id := fnd_gfm.authorize (NULL);
  x_access_id := v_access_id;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Access id :' || v_access_id);
  -- The function fnd_gfm.confirm_upload return the file id
  v_file_id :=
     fnd_gfm.confirm_upload (access_id            => v_access_id
                           , file_name            => v_filename
                           , program_name         => 'TEST'
                           , program_tag          => 'TEST'
                           , expiration_date      => NULL
                           , LANGUAGE             => 'US'
                           , wakeup               => TRUE
                            );
  x_file_id := v_file_id;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File id :' || x_file_id);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     x_errbuf := 'Procedure upload_file errored out with the following error : ' || SQLERRM;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x_errbuf);
END upload_file;
BEGIN
fnd_global.apps_initialize (0, 20634, 401);
load_file_details (p_name => p_file_name, result_set_curr => l_result_set_curr);
upload_file (v_filename => p_file_name, x_access_id => x_access_id, x_file_id => x_file_id);
COMMIT;
END;


DECLARE
TYPE result_set_type IS REF CURSOR;

l_name              VARCHAR2 (100);
l_doc_size          NUMBER;
l_result_set_curr   result_set_type;
x_access_id         NUMBER;
x_file_id           NUMBER;
p_file_name         VARCHAR2 (100)  := 'aa.pdf';

PROCEDURE attach_file (p_access_id IN NUMBER, p_file_Id in number, p_filename IN VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
      fnd_webattch.add_attachment (seq_num                  => 900
                                 ,category_id               => 1
                                 ,document_description      => 'Test1'
                                 ,datatype_id               => 5
                                 ,text                      => NULL
                                 ,file_name                 => p_filename
                                 ,url                       => NULL
                                 ,function_name             => 'INVIDITM'
                                 ,entity_name               => 'MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS'
                                 ,pk1_value                 => 85 --organization_id
                                 ,pk2_value                 => 10 --Inventory_item_Id
                                 ,pk3_value                 => NULL
                                 ,pk4_value                 => NULL
                                 ,pk5_value                 => NULL
                                 ,media_id                  => p_file_id
                                 ,user_id                   => 0
                                 ,usage_type                => 'O'
                                 );  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File Attached!');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('error in loading the attachement');
END attach_file;
BEGIN
fnd_global.apps_initialize (0, 20634, 401);
attach_file (p_access_id => x_access_id, p_file_id=>x_file_id,p_filename => p_file_name);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe we are mixing context here. I assume Local machine here means the machine that you build the PL/SQL - only issue here is when you run it runs within the server context. So i would either FTP the file to the server or load your file content to an oracle table in a different way.